# How to get distance between the start and end points of UIBezierPath arc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I want know what is the distance between the startangle and endangle of an arc drawed with UIBezierPath.

[image]

I'm trying get the NSPoints of the path like:

```
void getPointsFromBezier(void *info, const CGPathElement *element){
NSMutableArray *bezierPoints = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)info;
CGPathElementType type = element->type;
CGPoint *points = element->points;
if (type != kCGPathElementCloseSubpath)
{
    if ((type == kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint) ||
        (type == kCGPathElementMoveToPoint))
        [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[0]]];
    else if (type == kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint){
        [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[0]]];
        [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[1]]];
    }else if (type == kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint){
        [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[0]]];
        [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[1]]];
        [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[2]]];
    }
}
```

}

But if I know the end and start of angle, the radius size and the center, how can I get the distance?

Comment: Can't you just run the distance formula on points[0] and points[points.size - 1]?

Comment: But when I try get the x value of first point: [bezierPoints[0] x]  I get [NSConcreteValue x]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: You get that because you are storing points as `NSValue` in `bezierPoints`.. You need to do:  `[bezierPoints[0] CGPointValue].x`

Comment: It's true, I was getting this incorrectly, with CGPointValue I get this and I can use the distance formula sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)) to get my value, thanks!